# Gracenote API: GnAlbum (method of Gracenote android GNSDK)

Tags: java, android, api, gracenote

What is a identifier tag of GnAlbum?

GnAlbum(java.lang.String id, java.lang.String idTag)

```
      Constructs a GnAlbum object from identifier and identifier tag
```

I don't know identifier tag.

I can get identifier. GnMusicIdFileInfo fileInfo.identifier(); isn't it?

But I don't know identifier tag.

Thans for your help.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? Normally GNAlbum would be created from a response to Gracenote service query and would not need to create this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create GnAlbum yourself. It should be returned as a result when querying Gracenote API.